# center element that gets pushed whit float:left

Tags: html, css

Float left causes elements to get pushed to the next row, once the space is scarse. How do you center the newly pushed element in the space that it has remaining, so that it doesn't sit to the left, but in the center.

Lets take this code for example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdPVwe. The green section gets pushed to the next row, but it is left aligned. How do you center it in the current window width once it is pushed?

```
<div>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
</div>  

section {
  width: 33%;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;

}

section:last-child {
  background-color:green;
  margin-right: 0%;
}
div{
  width:78%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you may want to rethink a different strategy. Flex is kind of scary at first but very useful and powerful.

On the wrapper you can do `display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;`. This comes out very nice.

Here is codepen example:
http://codepen.io/sequential/pen/LxvJrr

Here is a great article when learning flexbox.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @sanjihan Yeah for me too because flex property names are not as intuitive ... like what the hell is a flex, but it is definitely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need to float the boxes, but you could apply `display:inline-block;` to the children and `text-align:center;` to the parent.

```css
section {
  width: 300.33px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
}

section:last-child {
  background-color:green;
  margin-right: 0%;
}
div{
  width:78%;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<section></section><section></section><section></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `float:left;` use `display:inline-block;` and then add `text-align:center;` to the parent div.

```css
section {
  width: 300.33px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

section:last-child {
  background-color:green;
  margin-right: 0%;
}
div{
  width:78%;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using flexbox. Have the parent for the element you want centered `flex-grow` to take up the available space left over, then use `justify-content: center;` to center it in that space.

```css
.outer {
  width: 78%;
  margin: auto;
}
section {
  width: 300.33px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.center section {
  background-color:green;
  margin-right: 0%;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.center {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex outer">
  <div class="flex">
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </div>
  <div class="flex center">
    <section></section>
  </div>
</div>
```